# Get url's from google images

Tags: c#, google-image-search

I'm using the follow code to get a list of all the images url's on a webpage. the target is to get all the images url's from google image search. my problem that i get only 20 url's and the url's photo are the small photos and not the real size.

here's the code:

```
public List<string> FetchImages(string Url)
{
    List<string> imageList = new List<string>();

    //Append http:// if necessary
    if (!Url.StartsWith("http://") && !Url.StartsWith("https://"))
        Url = "http://" + Url;

    string responseUrl = string.Empty;
    string htmlData = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(DownloadData(Url, out responseUrl));

    if (responseUrl != string.Empty)
        Url = responseUrl;

    if (htmlData != string.Empty)
    {
        string imageHtmlCode = "<img";
        string imageSrcCode = @"src=""";

        int index = htmlData.IndexOf(imageHtmlCode);
        while (index != -1)
        {
            //Remove previous data
            htmlData = htmlData.Substring(index);

            //Find the location of the two quotes that mark the image's location
            int brackedEnd = htmlData.IndexOf('>'); //make sure data will be inside img tag
            int start = htmlData.IndexOf(imageSrcCode) + imageSrcCode.Length;
            int end = htmlData.IndexOf('"', start + 1);

            //Extract the line
            if (end > start && start < brackedEnd)
            {
                string loc = htmlData.Substring(start, end - start);

                //Store line
                imageList.Add(loc);
            }

            //Move index to next image location
            if (imageHtmlCode.Length < htmlData.Length)
                index = htmlData.IndexOf(imageHtmlCode, imageHtmlCode.Length);
            else
                index = -1;
        }

        //Format the image URLs
        for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++)
        {
            string img = imageList[i];

            string baseUrl = GetBaseURL(Url);

            if ((!img.StartsWith("http://") && !img.StartsWith("https://"))
                && baseUrl != string.Empty)
                img = baseUrl + "/" + img.TrimStart('/');

            imageList[i] = img;
        }
    }

    return imageList;
}
private string GetBaseURL(string Url)
{
    int inx = Url.IndexOf("://") + "://".Length;
    int end = Url.IndexOf('/', inx);

    string baseUrl = string.Empty;
    if (end != -1)
        return Url.Substring(0, end);
    else
        return string.Empty;
}
private byte[] DownloadData(string Url, out string responseUrl)
{
    byte[] downloadedData = new byte[0];
    try
    {
        //Get a data stream from the url
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Url);
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        responseUrl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();

        //Download in chuncks
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        //Get Total Size
        int dataLength = (int)response.ContentLength;

        //Download to memory
        //Note: adjust the streams here to download directly to the hard drive
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        while (true)
        {
            //Try to read the data
            int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //Write the downloaded data
                memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }

        //Convert the downloaded stream to a byte array
        downloadedData = memStream.ToArray();

        //Clean up
        stream.Close();
        memStream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        responseUrl = string.Empty;
        return new byte[0];
    }

    return downloadedData;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know, why you get only 20 images, but I believe, I have an answer for getting small images: The fact is, they are not physically there on page load. If you inspect element on page, you will find, that all the page is completely handled with javascript, dynamically loading images and url's on users interaction. Plain page after load really contains only small images.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you scraping images from Google or another site?

Comment: From Google..maybe somebody knows other image Search engine?

Comment: From Google..maybe somebody knows other image Search engine?

Answer (score 0):

Google only seems to load a certain amount of images at a time.  When you scroll on your computer, they load more.  Could it be that if it reaches an image that hasn't been populated it considered that the end of images?